# Fundamental Lemma of Variational Calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I'm reading over the following lemma and proof related to the fundamental lemma of variational calculus.

If $\color{red}{\alpha ∈ C([a,b])}$ and

$$\int^b_a [\alpha(x)h(x) + \beta(x)h'(x)] \ dx = 0$$

for every function $h ∈ C^1([a,b])$ such that $h(a) = h(b) = 0$, then

(1) $\beta(x)$ is differentiable almost everywhere on $[a, b]$

(2) $\beta'(x)$ = $\alpha(x)$

I understand the proof for the above lemma.  However, one of the exercises at the end of the section is as follows.

If $\color{red}{\alpha ∈ L^1([a,b])}$ and

$$\int^b_a [\alpha(x)h(x) + \beta(x)h'(x)] \ dx = 0$$

for every function $h ∈ C^1([a,b])$ such that $h(a) = h(b) = 0$, then

(1) $\beta(x)$ is differentiable almost everywhere on $[a, b]$

(2) $\beta'(x)$ = $\alpha(x)$

My question: wouldn't both proofs be relatively the same?

Comment: A function in $L^1$ need not be continuous, so examine the original proof and see if the continuity of $\alpha$ is invoked anywhere. Those steps will need to be substituted with arguments using the properties of $L^1$ functions

Comment: I would guess that you need to establish the fundamental lemma for $\alpha \in L^1$ first, then the proof follows.

Comment: Are you familiar with measure theory?